# Update multiple S3 bucket permissions in command line

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 50+ buckets in S3 and want to enable "list" permission to "Authenticated Users" of all buckets. How to do it in linux command line ?

Answer (score 0):

For all buckets in the account, this should do it:

```
buckets=$(aws s3api list-buckets --query="Buckets[*].Name" --output=text)
for b in $buckets
do
  echo "Adding List to AuthUsers on $b" 
  aws s3api put-bucket-acl \
    --bucket $b \
    --grant-read 'uri="http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers"'  
done
```

Adjust filters and permissions to your case, no warranties :)

For more s3 api commands, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html